# nodejs express scaffold app fails silently

Tags: 14.04, webserver, nodejs, vps

I'm just now the new proud owner of a very small unmanaged VPS (I want to learn how to do everything myself :>). I'd say I'm between beginner and intermediate or intermediate in unix/bash-fu but I'm not sure how to solve this problem:

Getting the default scaffolded (using the npm express-generator package) express app fails silently, and I have no idea why and if there is a verbose mode I can turn on (nodejs does not say it has such a mode, at least).

on both my local machine as my remote VPS, a newly scaffolded express app (as per [this instruction](http://expressjs.com/starter/generator.html)) fails silently.

[the left screenshot is a Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS VPS, the other is my local OSX 10.10](https://cloudup.com/cwN1rs6CWBu)

My first express project is public and can be found [on github](https://github.com/michahell/drake-equation-hype).

I found an answer to another node app failing silently, which was due to relative paths. I tried adding the nodejs reserved keyword **__dirname** to the relative paths I could find, however that did not solve the problem unfortunately.

I have only very little knowledge of Ubuntu, if there are ubuntu or nodejs logs I could check I'd love to learn the location of them!

Comment: Could you add some details about how you installed Node? Do you have to use `sudo` when you `npm install` modules?  If you run `which express` what does it tell you? Also, downvoter, care to explain yourself?